# Как сохранить в WebView кеш? Kotlin/Android Studio

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Подскажите как мне сделать, чтобы когда я пере заходил в приложение WebView не сбрасывало пароль и логин. Или как сохранить кеш в котлине?

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть вопроса, почему вы решили, что нужно сохранять именно кэш? Скорей всего, вам нужно сохранять cookies, а не кэш.

Comment: Да, скорее всего, просто еще новичок, подскажите пожалуйста, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста, очень надо)